# Confusion on simple probability question

Tags: probability, fractions, bayes-theorem

Suppose you take a ball at random without knowing which urn you took it from. Here are two kinds of urns, one with three red balls and one blue, and one with three blue balls and one red. Both urns are equally likely. The ball turns out to be blue. What is the probability of getting two blue balls without knowing which bin they came from?

Answer: 5/16

I'm confused on how this answer is derived. My reasoning was that there are 8 balls and 4 are blue. The chance of drawing a blue ball the first time is $\frac {1}{2}$ and the second time is still $\frac {1}{2}$ (assuming replacement). $\frac {1}{2} * \frac {1}{2} = \frac {1}{4}$.

Comment: Bayes theorem to the rescue!!

Comment: If you take a blue ball first then it probably came from the 3 blue, 1 red urn, so the conditional probability that the second ball is also blue is more than $\frac12$

Comment: I'm confused on how I'd use Bayes theorem for this. The denominator would be $\frac{1}{2}$ because that is the chance of drawing a blue ball, but what would go in the numerator since the question said "without knowing which bin they came from"?

Comment: @stumped see my answer. I walk you through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A1 denote the event "first urn selected". Let A2 denote the event "second urn selected". Let B denote the event "both balls are blue".

P(B|A1) = probability that both balls are blue given that the first urn was selected = (1/4)(1/4) = 1/16.

P(B|A2) = probability that both balls are blue given that the second urn was selected = (3/4)(3/4) = 9/16.

P(A1) = probability of selecting the *first* urn (note: unconditional probability, not the probability given you already know that the two balls are blue) = .5, this is given (it states the urns are equally likely to be chosen)

P(A2) = probability of selecting the *second* urn (note: unconditional probability, not the probability given you already know that the two balls are blue) = .5, this is given (it states the urns are equally likely to be chosen)

P(B) = probability of both balls being blue= P(B|A1)P(A1) + P(B|A2)P(A2) = (1/16)(1/2) + (9/16)(1/2) = 10/32 = 5/16

*Now you might ask, Given 2 blue balls were chosen, what is the probability the urn selected was the first one (A1) or the probability the urn selected was the second one (A2)?*

P(A1|B) = P(B|A1)P(A1)/P(B) = (1/16)(1/2)/(5/16) = 1/10 or about 10%

P(A2|B) = 1 - P(A1|B) = 1 - 1/10 = 9/10 or about 90%

The conclusion would be: Given that I picked 2 blue balls, there is about a 90% chance it was from A2, whereas only about a 10% chance it was from A1.. This make sense because A2 contains 3 blue balls compared to A1 which contains only 1.

Cheers

Comment: Ok, but why shall be both balls coming from one of the urn ? cannot the first ball come from one urn and the second from the other?

Comment: @GCab Does the question specify that? Yes this COULD happen, but that change all of this answer

Comment: If I were to answer: In the same experiment, using Bayes’ rule, compute the probability of a majority-blue bin after two blue balls in a row. What is this probability? Would I use $\frac{5}{16}$ as the denominator?

Comment: That I don't know. Sorry I did my best answering the initial question

Comment: Sorry that was a diverge from the original question, and I accidentally submitted my comment too early. Thanks for your help, it cleared up a lot of things!

Comment: If $P(B|A_1)$ could be read as the unconditional probability or the probability of $B$ given $A_1$, how would we distinguish the difference, by situation only?

Comment: @Brandon: no, infact the question does not specify where the two ball comes from. It should have been " ..two blue balls **from the same urn** without knowing which ...". In this case your answer is right. Otherwise the OP's assumption of $1/4$ would be correct.

Comment: @GCab I just made the assumption that they both came from the same urn. Most urn questions I've dealt with consist on pulling from the same urn. i.e, If you pull 2 balls and the first is from urn 1 then the second pull will be from urn 1 also..But it is certainly plausible to pull from urn 1 and then urn 2.

Comment: Im assuming the textbook stated that they both come from the same urn, otherwise the question is easy. And if the given answer was 5/16 to begin with, his initial method is obviously incorrect, given the context of choosing from the same urn